# How to properly terminate / unsubscribe mergeMap of a list of Observables omitting endless stream / .next() only

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Assume several Observables of long streams merged by mergeMap.
E.g:

```
export class TestClass {

  test() {
                                // each of these Observables has many other values 
                                // - are a stream of emitted values over time
    const observableA = of(1, 2, 3, 4, ...);              
    const observableB = of(0, -1, -2, -3, -4, ...);
    const observableC = of('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', ...);
    const observableD = of(true, true, false, true, ...);
    // etc...

    const observablesList = [
      observableA,
      observableB,
      observableC,
      observableD,
    ]

    from(observablesList).pipe(
      mergeMap(o => o)
    ).subscribe(v => this.handleValue(v));

  }
  private handleValue(val) {
    console.log(val);
  }
```

Each of the listed Observables has many other values.
The values are being emitted as a stream of values over time.

I have 3 questions on the termination of these merged Observables.

1. Assuming they all keep emitting and I want to terminate all (unsubscribe from all).
   How is that done on the merged map?
2. Can I unsubscribe from only one or some? If yes, how?
3. Assuming 1 of the Observables completes or emits an error. It terminates automatically.
   How are the others impacted? Do they terminate too? If not, how to terminate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try takeUntil pipe operator, and you only need to unSubscribe those you have subscribed.

```
this.unSub = new Subject();
...
from(observablesList).pipe(
  mergeMap(o => o),
  takeUntil(this.unSub)
).subscribe(v => this.handleValue(v));


ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unSub.next();
    this.unSub.complete();
}
```